# resteasy-jackson-provider returns invalid JSON EAP 6.2

Tags: java, rest, jboss, resteasy

I couldn't find an answer so I thought I would post this question.  I have a sample project where I am using EAP 6.2 , RESTEasy & resteasy-jackson-provider to retrieve data from an EJB 3.

However my results aren't what I would expect.

```
public class MyEJB3Bean implements MyBean {

@GET
@Produces("application/JSON")
@PermitAll
public Person getMyTestStuff(){
    Person m = new Person();
    m.setEmail("myemail@email.com");
    m.setId(new Long(12345));
    m.setName("Tony Stark");
    m.setPhone("208-555-1900");
    return m;

}}
```

I have defined the dependency in the pom.xml file and my results look like this:

- !!com.acme.model.Person {email: myemail@email.com, id: 12345, name: Tony Stark,
  phone: 208-555-1900}

It's providing the full class path of the object and not converting to JSON.

If I try the resteasy-jackson-provider2 it throws all kinds of errors.

Is there a setting I am missing?  I can't seem to find anything on it.

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: I didn't have my maven dependencies correct.  I needed to ensure the correct jars were included in the JBOSS deployment.  That fixed it.